# Javascript: wrong date calculation

Tags: javascript, html

So I just have posted a question about this code (which was answered):

```
$(document).ready(Main); 

function Main() { 
    ConfigDate();         
} 


function ConfigDate() { 
    var currentTime = new Date(); 
    var dayofWeek = currentTime.getDay(); 

    var daysSinceThursday = (dayofWeek + 3) % 7 
    var lastThursday = new Date(currentTime.getDate() - daysSinceThursday); 
    var dd = lastThursday.getDate(); 

    var mm = lastThursday.getMonth() + 1; 
    var yyyy = lastThursday.getFullYear(); 

    $("#last_thursday").text(yyyy + " / " + mm + " / " + dd); 
}
```

The problem now is that the date that appears in my cell is 1969 / 12 / 31 (which isn't even a thursday).

Did I do something wrong while calculating last thursday date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to set a Date based only on the day of the month of the last Thursday. Try something like this:

```
var daysSinceThursday = (dayofWeek + 3) % 7;
var lastThursday = new Date(currentTime.getTime());
lastThursday.setDate(currentTime.getDate() - daysSinceThursday);
var dd = lastThursday.getDate();

var mm = lastThursday.getMonth() + 1; 
var yyyy = lastThursday.getFullYear();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rAuRF/3/

Comment: Note that after this operation, `currentTime` will also be set to last Thursday because `lastThursday` and `currentTime` both refer to the same `Date` object.  To set `lastThursday` without modifying `currentTime`, you need to create a new `Date`.  To copy a date: `var lastThursday = new Date(currentTime.valueOf())`.  But, in this instance, you don't really need a copy.  You can just do: `var lastThursday = new Date()`

Comment: @gilly3: Good point. What I was really trying to do was keep the rest of the OP's code intact, but if `currentTime` is accessed after `lastThursday` had modified the `Date` then it would be incorrect. I've updated the code and fiddle

Answer (score 3):

This is because `.getDate()` returns the day of the month.  So you are building your date based on a serial number of something less than 30, which won't even set your seconds above 1.

Use `.setDate()` instead of building a new date:

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() - daysSinceThursday);
```

`.setDate()` will modify your existing date object, it doesn't return a new date.